# Codeigniter Special charcter print in function

Tags: php, codeigniter, special-characters

I am going to pass european to  the function from url like

URL : www.demo.com/controller/function/MAINä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,Ä,Ë,Ï,Ö,Ü,Ÿ

now i want to print parameter into function as it is in url

like this :  `MAINä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,Ä,Ë,Ï,Ö,Ü,Ÿ`

Please help thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your use case for this ? if you need a speaking url or something like that you should create a slug function (or even a db field) for that purpose (take a look at the wp core - they have a nice one...)

Comment: I am using codeigniter famwork.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work in your code, just try it.

Replace this to your `Config.php` file.

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';
```

Comment: Actually its for allow all character, its already working fine, i just want to print out last one parameter as it is into function but for now it converting this parameter like this 'MAIN%C3%A4,%C3%AB,%C3%AF,%C3%B6,%C3%BC,%C3%BF,%C3%84,%C3%8B,%C3%8F,%C3%96,%C3%9C,%C5%B8' and i want to print 'MAINä,ë,ï,ö,ü,ÿ,Ä,Ë,Ï,Ö,Ü,Ÿ'

Answer (score 0):

In short, you can't.

Per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), which describes Uniform Resource Locators (URL), only alpha-numeric characters, and some special characters, are permitted. Anything else would be encoded.

European characters as you call them, are not permitted in a URL and is why they are being encoded.

Have a look at [urldecode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode the url.

```
<?php
$url = "MAIN%C3%A4,%C3%AB,%C3%AF,%C3%B6,%C3%BC,%C3%BF,%C3%84,%C3%8B,%C3%8F,%C3%96,%C3%9C,%C5%B8";
$decoded = urldecode($url);
echo $decoded;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, i have already tried this but output is not  exactly what i m passing, its something different '"MAINÃ¤,Ã«,Ã¯,Ã¶,Ã¼,Ã¿,Ã„,Ã‹,Ã,Ã–,Ãœ,Å¸" is ""'

Comment: can you please guide me how to use this urldecode function with my condition

Comment: Post your code and I can help you. Otherwise, I've updated my answer to show you how to use urldecode().